# Selecting attribute in xml

Tags: c#, xml, binding, windows-phone-8, xml-parsing

I am trying to select "Example language" in the xml code below. 
This is the C#:

```
XNamespace gml = "http://www.example.net/gdl";
XElement Xmlwater = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

listBox3.ItemsSource = from Zwemwater in Xmlwater.Descendants(zwr + "Location")
        select new water
{
       water_name = water.Element(zwr + "Name").Value,
       water_language = water.Element(zwr + "language").Value, // How to select the "nl" ? 
};
```

This is the XML:

```
<zwr:Location>
   <zwr:Name>test<zwr:Name>
   <zwr:Example language="nl"> Example text </zwr:beschrijving>
   <zwr:Example language="en"/> 
</zwr:Location>
```

What is the best way to get the  Example language="nl so that i can bind it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `water` is `<zwr:Location>` element, you can do as follow :

```
water_language = water.Element(zwr + "Example").Attribute(zwr + "language").Value
```

That will select child element of `Location` that has name `Example`, then get value of that child element's `language` attribute. PS: *I'm not sure if attribute name considering namespace or not, but in the sample above I assume it is*

Comment: Thank you very much. Any idea how i can get the "Example text" too? Thanks Again

Comment: you already done it for `Name` element: `water.Element(zwr + "Name").Value`. Just change "Name" there, to "Example".

Comment: Well ofcource. Only thing is that the xml I use starts with the empty one "<zwr:Example language="en"/>" and after that the one with the text "example text". what is the best way to select only the "nl" info(example text)? Thanks.

Comment: you can try this: `water.Elements(zwr + "Name").FirstOrDefault(o => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.Value))`. That will select first `Name` element that has inner text like the "example text".

Comment: `water.Elements(zwr + "Name").FirstOrDefault(o => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.Value)).Value ` did the trick. Thanks for all the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the .Attributes property instead of the .Element property.

```
water_language = water.Attributes(zwr + "language").Value
```